# jsxファイルをjsファイルで記述するにはどんなパッケージが必要なのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, npm, react-jsx

create-react-appにでプロジェクトを開始すると、最初から拡張子が.jsファイル内にjsx記法を使うことができますが、一体どのパッケージがその処理を担っているのでしょうか

react-scriptsがよしなにやってくれているとは思うのですが、
react-scriptsは裏側でいろんなパッケージをinstallしていたり設定ファイルを書いていたりするイメージがあり、結局どのパッケージがjsxをjsファイル内でも記述できるようにしているのか疑問です。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは、 meru さん

ご質問のjsx記法の処理についてですが、基本的には `babel` というJavaScriptコンパイラがその役割を担っています。
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/#jsx-and-react

さらに具体的には、以下のプラグインで `jsx` から `JavaScriptオブジェクト` にトランスパイルしているので、ご質問の機能は以下で実行されています。
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

参考になれば、幸いです。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます！babel、トランスパイル系のことを色々やってくれている印象はありましたが、jsx→jsへの対応もしているのですね。ありがとうございます！試させていただきます！！